# MavensMate Firewall issues

Tags: metadata-api, eclipse, tooling-api, mavensmate

I am behind a very strict firewall at work and I am moving from Eclipse to MavensMate (+Sublime).

Eclipse can both send and receive metadata from Salesforce fine, but MavensMate is not making it through my company firewall.

I have tried to emulate what Eclipse is doing in MM by switching the Tooling API to the MetaData API and trying out version 28 but I still can't make it through the company firewall to commit/retrieve metadata from SFDC.

Does anybody have any advice on why Eclipse is working and why MM is not? Also any assistance e.g. an IP pool to whitelist in the firewall or some settings to apply in MM/Sublime would be greatly appreciated.

Really want to stop using Eclipse and adopt MM... Please help :)

**EDIT:** I would like to mention that we have a proxy here but the group cert in Windows is shot and the proxy is terrible. I can use MM through the proxy but I would like to unblock directly from firewall is possible...

Comment: I know that MavensMate will fire up a local server to handle some of the work, at least it does on my Mac. That may be part of the issue if the firewall on your machine is blocking localhosts from running.

Comment: I worked briefly with the network admin and we identified an IP that was being blocked and permitted it through the firewall. Immediately after we noticed it tried to connect to another IP and the network admin requested that I find out all IP addresses required for the transaction (and if they are static or require a pool) so that we can unblock them at once.

Comment: I am a little concerned that all these additional calls are being made that Eclipse clearly does not make. If possible I would like to have MavensMate call the same services as Eclipse but this may not be possible based on the solution.

Comment: I should also identify that these blockages were identified at the corporate firewall, not local machines

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to the team behind mavensmate and asking for clarification on what network access they require.

Comment: Currently have a ticket open but from my understanding it is less of a "team" and more of a "guy" so not sure how long I need to wait for an answer (the support forum has very low volume of traffic). Was hoping with the high adoption rate of this tool that someone here would be able to provide assistance...

Answer (score 0):

As others have already suggested - make sure that your local machine firewall does not block localhost/127.0.0.1 which MM uses to run its server part.
Also make sure you are on the current version, as there have been some reports (along the same lines) in the past: https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/issues/558

> find out all IP addresses required for the transaction

MavensMate-SublimeText is an open source project, so you can check what MavensMate wants to access yourselves by searching for “http” in [Github repository](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText)

Here are few examples

- it sends usage statistics to https://mavensmate.appspot.com, [see here](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/blob/master/lib/community.py#L98).
  This statistics can be turned off in settings, [see here](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/blob/master/mavensmate.sublime-settings#L113)
- on Linux it uses http://ip.42.pl/ to resolve IP address 
  https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/blob/master/lib/community.py#L42
- then there is some activity around [mm_community_api_token](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/blob/master/lib/community.py#L88) (statistics again). Requests being sent to https://mavensmate.herokuapp.com/

There are may be other places  (other than SFDC servers and localhost) which it tries to access, but list of examples above should be sufficient to give you an idea that IP based firewall rules probably will not do it, because things like herokuapp.com or appspot.com can change their IP frequently.

Also, it is unlikely that open access to any of the above “statistics” URLs is actually needed for MM to function.